# Karma not breaking on missing component

Tags: angular, karma-runner

We are seeing errors in tests when child components are not imported/declared, however the tests are not failing. This has over time caused that these tests have been added to the codebase.
[image]

We'd like to ensure that these actually break the tests though so that we can prevent them from being committed.

Is there a way we can make this fail the tests?

**How to reproduce:**

- Create new project
- Create new module and component `child` (and export component)
- Import `child` module in app module
- Add `<app-child></app-child>` to `app.component.html`

`ng run build/start` works fine, however `ng run test` throws:

```
ERROR: 'NG0304: 'app-child' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-child' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-child' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.'
Chrome Headless 88.0.4324.150 (Mac OS 11.2.1): Executed 1 of 2 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.028 secs)
ERROR: 'NG0304: 'app-child' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-child' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
Chrome Headless 88.0.4324.150 (Mac OS 11.2.1): Executed 2 of 2 SUCCESS (0.051 secs / 0.037 secs)
TOTAL: 2 SUCCESS
```

Comment: please provide more information about the test itself

Comment: @GérômeGrignon I have added reproduction steps, let me know if this is clear enough? The test itself is the default `it('should create the app', () => {` in the update. It doesn't matter what the actual test is for these errors, in errors on every test when parsing the template

Comment: which version of angular-cli are you using?

Comment: Latest, V11.2.0. Also found this now: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/36430